# Excel formula changed using ; instead of ,

Tags: excel

usually i write formula in Microsoft Excel 2010 using , (comma) like this

=if(A1=A2,True, False)

But now it changes to ; (semi-colon) like this

=if(A1=A2;True;False)

How can I change it back to comma?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your Regional settings. When you use a region setting where commas are used for decimal separators, Excel uses semicolons to separate function arguments.

Comment: OMG..... i've looking for this week and i can't found it..... thank you for your super quick answer.